# ORACLE DB Optimizing an Update query to update all null values in a column based on data in other tables

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I recently made this script in ORACLE DB to update all the existing values on a column I just created. However I was informed that the exists function is extremely slow and that I should use update using join instead. Unfortunately I am having trouble finding useful examples and/or information on how to do that properly in ORACLE DB.

```
UPDATE appeal app
SET app.is_initial = (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1
                                             FROM appeal app_sub
                                                      JOIN event_person ep ON app_sub.id = ep.appeal_id
                                                      JOIN event ON ep.event_id = event.id
                                             WHERE event.name_code = 'INITIAL' AND app.id = app_sub.id)
                                     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
WHERE app.is_initial IS NULL;
```

If anyone knows how to do that, I would really appreciate the help. PS. I have changed the names of the tables for security.

Comment: Please add the [execution plan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/4808122) of the query explaining *why* it is slow. Qualify all columns in your query so the source table of them is clear. Add information about the size of the tables and the number of *nullls*. Without this information only general guessing is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EXISTS` isn't necessarily slow, but can be. Here's a few things to check:

Do you have indexes on `app.id`, `event_person.appeal_id` and `event.id` ? Unless Oracle rewrites this, the standard `EXISTS` subquery will use nested loops and you'll need to have the join columns indexed properly so that it performs well. Simply ensuring that these indexes are in place will probably resolve your issue without having to rewrite your SQL. If you have a small data set this is all I'd recommend you do.

However, you can generally get better performance for very large volumes  by using `MERGE`, which enables you do use more efficient parallel and direct path scans and hash joins for assembling data to drive updates. It would generally *not* use indexes, for the most part. It'd look something like this (over-hinted just be make the point (and be certain), most of these hints are probably unnecessary).

```
ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL DML;

MERGE /*+ USE_HASH(src app) parallel(app,8) */ INTO appeal app
USING (SELECT /*+ parallel(8) NO_MERGE USE_HASH(app_sub ep event) */
              app_sub.id,
              MAX(DECODE(event.id,NULL,0,1)) at_least_one
         FROM appeal app_sub
              LEFT OUTER JOIN event_person ep ON app_sub.id = ep.appeal_id
              LEFT OUTER JOIN event ON ep.event_id = event.id
        WHERE name_code = 'INITIAL'
          AND app_sub.is_initial IS NULL
        GROUP BY app_sub.id) src
   ON (src.id = app.id)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET app.is_initial = src.at_least_one
```

(I don't know what table `name_code` comes from; make sure it is *not* indexed, or if it is, ensure Oracle is not using that index and add a `FULL([table])` hint to prevent it from doing so if it is.)

Lastly, for extremely large volumes the most optimal way is to not update at all, but to create a new table and replace the old one:

```
CREATE TABLE appeal2 parallel (degree 8)
AS
SELECT /*+ USE_HASH(app epx) */
       app.id,
       app.col1,
       app.col2,
       app.col3,
       NVL(app.is_initial,DECODE(apx.appeal_id,NULL,0,1)) is_initial
  FROM appeal app
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT /*+ NO_MERGE USE_HASH(ep event) */
                               ep.appeal_id,
                          FROM event_person ep
                               INNER JOIN event ON ep.event_id = event.id
                         WHERE name_code = 'INITIAL'
                         GROUP BY ep.appeal_id) epx ON epx.appeal_id = app.appeal_id;

ALTER TABLE appeal RENAME TO appeal_old;
ALTER TABLE appeal2 RENAME TO appeal;

-- also rebuild and indexes, constraints and reissue grants.
```

New segment creation is always much, much faster and more efficient than updating every row of a table. If the table is small, it's not worth the additional steps, but if you're talking hundreds of millions or billions of rows, this is your most performant method.

Comment: I'm not sure your `at_least_one` logic is correct in the `CREATE TABLE` query as you are overwriting any existing non-`NULL` value. I think it ought to be `COALESCE(app.is_initial, DECODE(epx.appeal_id,NULL,0,1))` (and you have got a typo in the alias as you use both `epx` and `apx`)

Comment: @MT0 duly noted, thx

Comment: In our local environments there were about 9 million rows that were affected and I believe in the live one there are more, so sadly it isn't a small data set. But I will try the merge strategy.

Comment: I tested your query, but it only affected around 17k rows of the 9 million. I'm not sure where the mistake is, but maybe just to clarify the new column is_initial requires a value no matter what, so all the rows should either receive a 1 or a 0 in that column. Forgive my mediocre SQL knowledge, this is just a little bit advanced for me.

Comment: Ohh, I think I understand now, your query only sets the values of the rows that are tied to the "IS_INITIAL" code to 1, but doesn't assign 0 to the rest of the rows.

Comment: @JuhanTamm, no, it tries to imitate your original SQL logic, which doesn't change `is_initial` if it already has a value. If it is `NULL`, then update to either 1 or 0 depending on whether a matching row was found in the `epx` view. If that's not the logic you want, it should be easy to adapt as desired. The point of my answer is the technique for addressing your performance concern, not the exact code. Also, with 9 million rows to update, you may want to do `alter session enable parallel dml` . I've edited my answer with this addition and accompanying hint.

Comment: I received some help from inside my team as well, but even so thank you for investing your time and your answer was still helpful. It turned out that finding the rows matching the desired condition indeed wasn't necessarily the taxing part, but rather just updating 9 million rows. This simply wasn't suitable for a propagation script. However, we found a workaround of assigning a default value of 0 to the column and then based on your answer updating the required rows to true.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `Merge` using `left join` :-

```
 MERGE INTO  appeal TRG
 USING(
 SELECT appeal.id,CASE WHEN appeal_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END NEW_VAL
 FROM appeal app_sub
 LEFT JOIN event_person ep ON app_sub.id = ep.appeal_id
 INNER JOIN event ON ep.event_id = event.id
 WHERE name_code = 'INITIAL' 
 )SRC
 ON (TRG.ID=SRC.ID)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
 set TRG.is_initial=SRC.NEW_VAL
 where TRG.is_initial IS NULL;
```

Comment: Your current suggestion's select query's id is ambiguous and thus cannot run, but i'll try to figure out which one it's supposed to reference.

Comment: It updates a few rows, but sth is missing.

Comment: @JuhanTamm updated answer `appeal.id`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `name_code` is in the `event` or `event_person` table then you do not appear to need to use `APPEAL` in the sub-query and can simplify it to:

```sql
UPDATE appeal app
SET app.is_initial = (SELECT LEAST(COUNT(*), 1)
                      FROM   event_person ep
                             INNER JOIN event
                             ON ep.event_id = event.id
                      WHERE  name_code = 'INITIAL'
                      AND    app.id = ep.appeal_id)
WHERE app.is_initial IS NULL;
```

or:

```sql
UPDATE appeal app
SET app.is_initial = COALESCE(
                       ( SELECT 1
                         FROM   event_person ep
                                INNER JOIN event
                                ON ep.event_id = event.id
                         WHERE  name_code = 'INITIAL'
                         AND    app.id = ep.appeal_id
                         AND    ROWNUM = 1 ),
                       0
                     )
WHERE app.is_initial IS NULL;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KEuzSq2K)